# Android - Access files from external sources

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a task in gradle here where I can access all files in my project and then validate the use of one lib.

Thinking about a multi-module project where all features are injected as dependencies from Artifactory, is there a way to access the files itself?

It could be in Gradle or not, but I need to throw a GradleException and not let the project build if an error occours.

Here what I have for files inside the project:

```
task checkValidUsage {
    doLast {
        def forbiddenPackage = "here a package"
        def allowedPackage = 'allowed package here'
        def sourceDir = "source dir here"
        def violationsFound = false
        def classViolation = ""
 
        fileTree(sourceDir).visit { visit ->
            if (visit.directory) return
 
            def inputPath = visit.path
 
            if (visit.file.text.contains(forbiddenPackage) && !inputPath.contains(allowedPackage)) {
                println("Uso do SDK fora do padrão na classe ${inputPath}. Por favor, consulte a nossa documentação.")
                violationsFound = true
                classViolation = inputPath
            }
        }
 
        if (violationsFound) {
            throw new GradleException("Uso do SDK fora do padrão na classe ${classViolation}")
        }
    }
}
 
preBuild.dependsOn 'checkValidUsage'
```